# Rectifying VS 2015 ant deployment with NativeScript

Tags: android, command-line, ant, visual-studio-2015, nativescript

I originally created a project at c:\source\project folder using the tns command line utility.  I created a new nativescript project just fine, but when I run the command for android:

```
tns platform add android
```

Yields the error:

> Error executing commands 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your PATH.

I was hoping to rectify the ant deployment through what VS 2015 installs and the path that NativeScript is depending upon, but it doesn't appear to work.  I setup `%ANT_HOME%` to point to the apache-ant folder that VS uses:

```
%ANT_HOME% = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3
```

But this isn't working correctly.  Is there a way to make nativescript use ant from the VS path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work:

1. Close/exit any open Windows Command window
2. Open/edit the environment variable `PATH` and add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3` to it, then save it. (I assume you know how to edit/change environment variables)
3. Open a new Command window (with Admin rights)
4. Go the root folder of your project
5. Type and run `tns platform add android` and see what happens